# Students enrol, professors... what?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

When a university student picks a class for a semester, they "**enrol**"*. When a professor chooses to teach a class for a semester, they... ?

I'm actually looking for a noun to use in parallel with "enrolment". The closest I can think of would be "assignment", but I hope there is a more specific term (and also "assignment" sounds too much like "homework").

<sub>* British English = *enrol*/*enrolment*. American English = *enroll*/*enrollment*</sub>

Comment: At my school, it was _offer_ or _teach_. For instance, _Professor X is offering/teaching "Bone Structure of the Ibex" this term_.

Comment: @John Lawler Did they have a skeleton staff?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It may have been a mutant staff.

Comment: @KannE -  I’m with you, it just looks very wrong as ***enrol***.  And I had no idea it was a Br/Am thing.

Comment: Well, active vs passive voice doesn't really make much difference in my case. Whether professors assign themselves or they get assigned by a dean, in both cases the net result is an "assignment". I'm looking for a synonym of "assignment" in this context.

Comment: It's not even comparably the same kind of procedure, so there's no opposition to have a term for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... professors get **appointed**.

> **Appointment**
>   [...] the state or fact of being chosen for a position or duty

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/appointment

Comment: Professors indeed get appointed to their positions, but a position in this context is something like XYZ Chair in Such-and-such Studies. Holding such a position is a long-term matter, and it does not by itself entail which specific courses will the person teach in a particular term (it only entails that they will be in the general area of such-and-such studies, but that is usually interpreted very broadly).

Answer (score 2):

There is no term that could fill in the blank in 'Professor P _____ course C' and would be analogous to 'Student S **enrolled in** course C', because the process that leads to P's teaching C is not at all analogous to enrolment. A student simply chooses a course, completes the necessary paperwork (or clicks on something on the university's website) and is then enrolled (assuming there are no special obstacles such as failure to pay the fees or lacking the prerequisites). There is nothing like this that a professor does.

The process that determines who teaches what depends on the nature and customs of the institution, the traditions of the academic field, the seniority of the professor, on whether the course is introductory or advanced, on whether the professor is regularly employed by the institution, visiting from another one, or hired only for the specific course, and so forth. (Incidentally, I am assuming that the OP is using the word *professor* casually, as is usual among the students on North America. That is, I am assuming that the question is about everybody who teaches in postsecondary education, not only those who hold the title of a professor.) In some cases, the decision is made at a departmental meeting, in others it is a matter of negotiation between the professor and the head of the department. Sometimes there is a great deal of back-and-forth discussion about the matter, sometimes very little. The preferences of a highly distinguished professor typically carry great weight in the process; the preferences of a junior one much less.

When professors talk among themselves, they may use the terms that reflect the specifics of the process in the particular case, such as 'P has chosen to teach C', 'P has been asked to teach C' or even 'P has taken C'. Such terms, however, cannot be used by the outsiders, who typically don't know whether, for example, P had much choice in the matter. One term that does not imply anything about the specifics of the process, and is thus probably the best for an outsider to use is 'Professor P **is scheduled to teach** course C.

Comment: Thank you for your long reply. I am indeed using the term "professor" in the loose sense. In fact, I have the same question if we consider a school with 3 math teachers who need to distribute 20 classes between themselves. Not much complex process in this case, perhaps some scheduling considerations (each teacher is fully qualified to each any math class). Each teacher ends up being "assigned" to teach a number of classes. I'm looking for a synonym of "assign". Yeah, I accept the likelihood that there isn't one :(

Answer (score 1):

Courses (or classes) are offered.

Students enroll in courses.

For a nominal form, try:

> *offering*(*s*)
>   *offered course*(*s*)
>   *course offering*(*s*)

Example:

> Verb: *The professor is offering Math 50 in the spring semester.*
>
> Noun: *The professor's course offerings for spring semester include
>   Math 50.*

Comment: While one does sometimes hear that a professor is offering a course, it is more usual for the phrase *to offer a course* to take some term referring to an institution as the subject, as in 'Our department is offering a course on . . . , which will be taught by Professor . . . .'